# FlexboxLayout - Show tag or Chip or label count at the end of second line android

Tags: android, material-design, flowlayout, android-chips, android-flexboxlayout

I am using **FlexboxLayout** for showing chips in android but stuck at UI Where I want to show number of chips count at the end of second line as per below screenshot[image]

As per above design I want to show chips until second line and the chips that not fit in second line should increase chip count at the end of chips

What I have check is

1- FlexboxLayout **setMaxLine(2);**  But in this case UI only two line draw and second line is strech

2- FlexboxLayout **getFlexLineInternel()** - this API gives wrong result. Count of line is increases after 1 item added in the line then it gives **getFlexLineInternel().size()** == 2  it means view is already added in third line but I want to restrict only on 2 lines.

3- Try with Material **Chip and ChipGroup** - It didn't given me number of lines draw in chipGroup

4- Try with **Flowlayout** similar as ChipGroup. Didn't given me number of lines draw by layout so that I can show count at end of second line

Please give me suggestion what is helpful in my situation

Here is my code

> activity_search_label.xml

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
      android:id="@+id/assetLabelsContainer"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_16"
      android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/size_16"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:flexWrap="wrap"/>
```

> LabelSearchActivity.java

```
   public class LabelSearchActivity extends SearchActivity {

  @BindView(R.id.assetLabelsContainer)
  public FlexboxLayout assetLabelsContainer;

  private int COUNTER_LABEL_ID = -1;
  private ArrayList<LabelModelParcelableItem> selectedLabels;
  private ArrayList<LabelModelParcelableItem> visibleSelectedList;
  private CompositeDisposable disposables;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    clearLabelList();
    showSelectedLabel();
  }

  public void hideSearchTitleCountView() {
    if (null != searchTitle) {
      searchTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
  }

  private void clearLabelList() {
    selectedLabels = new ArrayList<>();
    visibleSelectedList = new ArrayList<>();
    assetLabelsContainer.getFlexLinesInternal().clear();
    assetLabelsContainer.removeAllViews();
  }

  private void showSelectedLabel() {
    if (getIntent() != null) {
      Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
      if (bundle.getParcelableArrayList(SELECTED_LABEL_ITEMS) != null) {
        ArrayList<LabelModelParcelableItem> selectedLabels = bundle
            .getParcelableArrayList(SELECTED_LABEL_ITEMS);
        showLabelList(selectedLabels);
      }
    }
  }

  public void addViewToFlex(final LabelModelParcelableItem labelModelParcelableItem) {
    if (!selectedLabels.contains(labelModelParcelableItem)) {
      selectedLabels.add(labelModelParcelableItem);
      final View view = getChipView(labelModelParcelableItem);
      if (shouldShowCount()) {
        View countView = getCounterView();
        if (null != countView) {
          LabelModelParcelableItem tag = (LabelModelParcelableItem) countView.getTag();
          LabelModelParcelableItem updatedTag =
              new LabelModelParcelableItem(
                  tag.getLabelId(), String.valueOf(getInvisibleItemCount()), tag.getAssetCount());
          TextView textView = (TextView) countView.findViewById(R.id.labelNameText);
          textView.setText(" + " + updatedTag.getLabelName());
          countView.setTag(updatedTag);
          assetLabelsContainer.requestLayout();
        } else {
          addCounterView();
        }
      } else {
        visibleSelectedList.add(labelModelParcelableItem);
        assetLabelsContainer.addView(view);
      }
    }
  }

  public int getInvisibleItemCount() {
    ArrayList<LabelModelParcelableItem> itemList = new ArrayList<>(selectedLabels);
    itemList.removeAll(visibleSelectedList);
    return itemList.size();
  }

  private void addCounterView() {
    final View view =
        LayoutInflater.from(LabelSearchActivity.this)
            .inflate(R.layout.label, assetLabelsContainer, false);
    LabelModelParcelableItem item =
        new LabelModelParcelableItem(
            COUNTER_LABEL_ID, String.valueOf(getInvisibleItemCount()), COUNTER_LABEL_ID);
    view.setTag(item);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.labelNameText);
    textView.setText(" + " + item.getLabelName());
    view.setOnClickListener(v -> showLabelContainerScreen(getSelectedLabels()));
    if (getInvisibleItemCount() > 0) {
      assetLabelsContainer.addView(view);
    }
  }

  public View getChipView(final LabelModelParcelableItem item) {
    final View view =
        LayoutInflater.from(LabelSearchActivity.this)
            .inflate(R.layout.label, assetLabelsContainer, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.labelNameText);
    textView.setText(item.getLabelName());
    view.setOnClickListener(v -> removeViewFormFlex(view, item));
    return view;
  }

  private boolean shouldShowCount() {
    if (assetLabelsContainer.getFlexLinesInternal().size() > 2) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  private void updatedLabelAfterRemove() {
    if (null != getCounterView()) {
      if (getInvisibleItemCount() > 0) {
        ArrayList<LabelModelParcelableItem> itemList = new ArrayList<>(selectedLabels);
        itemList.removeAll(visibleSelectedList);
        Collections.sort(itemList, (o1, o2) -> o2.getLabelName().compareTo(o1.getLabelName()));
        if (!itemList.isEmpty()) {
          addViewAfterRemove(itemList.get(0));
        }
      } else {
        assetLabelsContainer.removeView(getCounterView());
      }
    }
  }

  private void addViewAfterRemove(LabelModelParcelableItem item) {
    final View labelView = getChipView(item);
    View countView = getCounterView();
    if (countView != null) {
      assetLabelsContainer.removeView(countView);
      visibleSelectedList.add(item);
      assetLabelsContainer.addView(labelView);
      addCounterView();
    } else {
      visibleSelectedList.add(item);
      assetLabelsContainer.addView(labelView);
    }
  }

  private View getCounterView() {
    View countView =
        assetLabelsContainer.getFlexItemAt(assetLabelsContainer.getFlexItemCount() - 1);
    if (null != countView) {
      LabelModelParcelableItem item = (LabelModelParcelableItem) countView.getTag();
      if (item != null && item.getLabelId() == -1) {
        return countView;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  private void showLabelList(ArrayList<LabelModelParcelableItem> selectedLabels) {
    for (LabelModelParcelableItem item : selectedLabels) {
      addViewToFlex(item);
      assetLabelsContainer.post(() -> assetLabelsContainer.requestLayout());
    }
  }

  public void addSelectedLabel(Parcelable label) {
    addViewToFlex((LabelModelParcelableItem) label);
  }

  public ArrayList<LabelModelParcelableItem> getSelectedLabels() {
    return selectedLabels;
  }

  public List<Parcelable> getUpdatedLabelList(List<? extends Parcelable> newParcelableList) {
    if (null != newParcelableList && !newParcelableList.isEmpty()) {
      newParcelableList.removeAll(getSelectedLabels());
      return new ArrayList<>(newParcelableList);
    } else {
      return new ArrayList<>();
    }
  }

  public void labelUpdateList(List dataList) {
    getSearchAdapter().clearAndUpdateList(dataList);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBackButtonPressed() {
    setActivityResult(getSelectedLabels());
  }

  public void setActivityResult(ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> searchableItem) {
    setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent().putParcelableArrayListExtra(SEARCH_RESULT, searchableItem));
    super.onBackButtonPressed();
  }

  public void addDisposable(Disposable disposable) {
    if (null == disposables) {
      disposables = new CompositeDisposable();
    }
    disposables.add(disposable);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    if (disposables != null && !disposables.isDisposed()) {
      disposables.clear();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
  }

  private void showLabelContainerScreen(List<? extends Parcelable> labels) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewLabelsActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList(
        LabelSelectionActivity.ARGUMENT_KEY, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) labels);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivityForResult(intent, LabelSelectionActivity.VIEW_ALL_LABEL_CODE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!getSelectedLabels().isEmpty()) {
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(
          SELECTED_LABEL_ITEMS, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) getSelectedLabels());
      setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    } else {
      this.finish();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
  }

  @OnClick(R.id.navBarBack)
  public void onBackButton() {
    onBackPressed();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode != LabelSelectionActivity.VIEW_ALL_LABEL_CODE) {
      return;
    }
    if (data == null) {
      return;
    }
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
      return;
    }
    if (!data.hasExtra(SELECTED_LABEL_ITEMS)) {
      return;
    }
    clearLabelList();
    ArrayList<LabelModelParcelableItem> selectedLabels =
        data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(SELECTED_LABEL_ITEMS);
    showLabelList(selectedLabels);
    updateAfterViewAllLabels(selectedLabels);
  }

  private void updateAfterViewAllLabels(ArrayList<LabelModelParcelableItem> labelsAfterRemoved) {
    ArrayList<LabelModelParcelableItem> listOfRemovedLabels = new ArrayList<>(getSelectedLabels());
    listOfRemovedLabels.removeAll(labelsAfterRemoved);
    for (LabelModelParcelableItem item :  labelsAfterRemoved) {
      //removeViewFormFlex(item);
    }
  }

  public void removeViewFormFlex(View view, LabelModelParcelableItem item) {
    if (selectedLabels.remove(item)) {
      if (selectedLabels.isEmpty()) {
        assetLabelsContainer.removeAllViews();
      } else {
        visibleSelectedList.remove(item);
        assetLabelsContainer.removeView(view);
      }
      updatedLabelAfterRemove();
      Comparator<LabelModelParcelableItem> compareByName =
          (o1, o2) -> o1.getLabelName().compareTo(o2.getLabelName());
      getSearchAdapter().addLabelItemToList(item, compareByName);
    }
  }
}
```

As per above code it look like below image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try to **measure** the height of `FlexboxLayout`  after each `flexboxLayout.addView(view)` and if the width increased that is mean you are in second line.

Comment: same code is present  in the getFlexLineInternel()  API after addView() call means view is already added to third line, I dont want to add third line, I want to check before view is added to third line is after adding view line is increase or not

Comment: firstly i am sorry i mean height not width i updated the answer

Comment: secondly when you measure flex layout and when height increase first time you are in secnd line ok?

Comment: then you will get the width of each view you add  and you will get screen width and sub it from views in second lines and if the result is negative that is mean you reach to the end of the line hope that help you

Comment: so is it help ?

Comment: Not help this getting complicated, Padding to view and space between view didn't allow me to do this

Comment: sure yo have to consider padding and margin to each view